# How does the Higgs field energy state relate to the tension of a Cosmic String?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, higgs, topology, cosmic-string

I understand these cracks are massless objects, but if a string has an apparent mass from its warping of spacetime, how does this relate to the higher energy value of the Higgs field the Cosmic String takes?

Most literature I find introduces line-defects in a generalised field, and then states "This is the Higgs-Field, the defect is a Cosmic String" without elaborating on *why* the Higgs field. What is the significance of the Higgs field in the context of Cosmic Strings?

Comment: Welcome to phys.SE! Can you point us to some of the literature you found that states that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.